# Selecting an index in a QListView

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt

This might be a stupid question, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to select the row of a given index in a QListView.

QAbstractItemView , QListView's parent has a setCurrentIndex(const QModelIndex &index). The problem is, I can't construct a QModelIndex with the row number I want since the row and column field of the QModelIndex has no mutators.

QTableView, which also inherits from QAbstractItemView has a selectRow(int row) function, why in the seven hells doesn't the QListView have this?

Good ol' windows forms has the SelectedIndex property on it's listviews.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You construct the QModelIndex by using the createIndex(int row, int column) function of the model you gave to the view.  QModelIndexes should only be used once, and must be created by the factory in the model.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it had to be something like this!

Comment: QAbstractListModel::createIndex is now protected. You'll have to use QAbstractListModel::index(int row, int column) or use createIndex inside of your model.

Answer (score 11):

[This](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/model-view-selection.html) should help you get started

```
QModelIndex index = model->createIndex( row, column );
if ( index.isValid() )
    model->selectionModel()->select( index, QItemSelectionModel::Select );
```

Answer (score 1):

My working sample at Qt4.8.0 (MSVC2010 Compiller) based on Michael Bishop

```
QStandardItemModel *Model = (QStandardItemModel *)this->ui->listView_OptionsCategories->model();
QModelIndex index = Model->index(this->ui->stackedWidget->currentIndex(), 0);
if ( index.isValid() )
    this->ui->listView_OptionsCategories->selectionModel()->select( index, QItemSelectionModel::Select );
```

Comment: Isn't this just selecting the current item rather than an arbitrary item?

Comment: QModelIndex index = Model->index( <any row index>, 0); // in my QListView programmatically selecting working fine

Answer (score 0):

For Qt 6.3.x:

```
void selectRowInQListView(int row, QListView *listView) {
    QModelIndex index = listView->model()->index(row, 0);
    if (index.isValid()) {
        //listView->selectionModel()->select(index, QItemSelectionModel::Select);
        //listView->selectionModel()->select(index, QItemSelectionModel::Current);
        listView->setCurrentIndex(index);
    }
}
```